# Ubuntu 12.04 login hangs on "Checking Battery" or "SANED," then returns to login screen

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, battery, sane

Working earlier tonight, my mouse froze in the middle of the screen, and so I restarted my system. Upon trying to log back in, the screen flashes black, and something along the lines of `saned: edit /etc/default/sane` and `Checking battery state` before it flashes back to the login screen.

I've scanned the askubuntu files which discuss a similar problem and I've purged and reinstalled: `nvidia-common`, `lightdm`, `ubuntu-desktop`, `gdm`, `gnome-power-manager`, `lightdm-gtk-greeter`, and `unity-greeter`. I've deleted `~/.Xauthority`.

My graphics card is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor
Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

so it shouldn't be a problem with nvidia anything.

I can log in as a guest user and with the TTY, but I just can't log in as my primary user.

Comment: Have you enabled autologin some time back? This happened to me earlier when i enabled autologin and upgraded my system.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration, same Intel 2nd generation .. Xubuntu 12.04, and same hangs after "checking battery state" from time to time.
I don't have any Nvidia driver.

Short-cut solution : You can log into tty and launch `startx`.